# Scripting GeoServer with Groovy

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, wps, geoscript, groovy

I'm trying to add a script to GeoServer so I can create my own [rendering transformation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html). However, I'm having trouble installing the scripting extension as outlined [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/index.html).

The script uses the [GeoScript Groovy API](http://geoscript.org/groovy/). I've added the groovy plugin files from the [nightly build server](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.11.x/community-latest/) to the WEB-INF/lib folder on my local machine, but I'm not getting the script directory appear in the GeoServer GUI after I restart. The docs only outline the process for installing the Python script extension, not the Groovy one.

I'm using GeoServer on my local machine which runs Windows 10. Is there something I'm missing to enable the scripting extension?

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: @iant it does not seem to be creating one. It's a brand new installation and the logs folder has one file in it called keepme.txt

Comment: does tomcat have write permission to the data directory?

Comment: @iant I used the standalone windows installer. So as I understand it, I don't need Tomcat. Is that correct?

Comment: OK then who ever runs geoserver needs write perms to the data dir, if you have no log file then scripting is the least of your issues, I'm surprised GeoServer starts at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the script extension, a script folder is created in the data_dir folder, it just does not appear in the GUI as the GeoServer [docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/ui.html) indicate it should.

I had to make a wps folder in the new scripts one. I copied my script to the wps folder and it now shows up in the WPS request builder

Turns out I was looking in the wrong log folder as suggested by @iant. Noob mistake!